# sub domain not working in my website

Tags: domain-name-system, debian, bind, subdomain

My subdomain is incaccessible since SEVERAL hours. This often do. They are inaccessible for a while and suddenly they are again accessible.

I didn't see the problem,  I configured bind9 like this :

```
$TTL 86400
@ IN SOA ks3309528.kimsufi.com. ******. (
        2013030310      ;serial
        3600            ;refresh
        600             ;retry
        2419200         ;expire
        600)            ;minimum
@        IN NS     ks3309528.kimsufi.com.
@        IN NS     ns.kimsufi.com.
yt-stats.com.       IN A      5.135.160.63
www                  IN CNAME  yt-stats.com.
beta                 IN CNAME  yt-stats.com.
```

And

```
$TTL 86400
@ IN SOA ks3309528.kimsufi.com. root.yt-stats.com. ( 
         2013030302 
         3600 
         600 
         241920
         600)
@        NS     ks3309528.kimsufi.com.

63      IN PTR  yt-stats.com.
```

For exemple beta.yt-stats.com is unavailable for some hours. 
When i use ping :

```
Ping request could not find host beta.yt-stats.com. Please check the name and try again.
```

edit ad more info :

```
/etc/resolv.conf
> nameserver 127.0.0.1

nano /etc/host.conf
> multi on

/etc/hosts
>
# Do not remove the following line, or various programs
# that require network functionality will fail.
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost
5.135.160.63       ks3309528.kimsufi.com
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
#(added automatically by netbase upgrade)
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

More info with **nslookup** :

**root@ks******:****/etc/bind# nslookup yt-stats.com**

```
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

Name:   yt-stats.com
Address: 5.135.160.63
```

**root@ks******:****/etc/bind# nslookup beta.yt-stats.com**

```
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

beta.yt-stats.com       canonical name = yt-stats.com.
Name:   yt-stats.com
Address: 5.135.160.63
```

root@ks******:/etc/bind#

**nano named.conf.default_zone**

```
one "yt-stats.com" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.ytstats";
        allow-transfer { 213.186.33.199; };
        allow-query { any; };
        notify yes;
};

zone "160.135.5.ain-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.ytstats.inv";
        forwarders{};
};
```

Comment: This sounds like a problem with your DNS provider, if the records haven't changed.  Can you verify that their authoritative servers are returning incorrect data by querying them directly?

Comment: How can i do that ?

Comment: `dig @ns.example.com beta.mywebsite.com` where `ns.example.com` is the authoritative server (the ones in your NS records).  Maybe also check all of the name servers that might be hosting your zone (in the NS records and/or in the name server delegations set up with your domain registrar) to see if maybe it's one specific server serving bad data.

Comment: @ShaneMadden see my edit, i added lot of information

Answer (score 0):

You've created the record on one of your name servers, but not the other - you're getting the record sometimes, while other times you're getting an `NXDOMAIN` response from the server that doesn't have the record, which is cached for a short time.

The server you're working on, 5.135.160.63 (ks3309528.kimsufi.com), has the record.  Your other name server, 213.186.33.199 (ns.kimsufi.com), does not.

However, the serial for the zone is the same for both, which is strange - are you updating the serial for the zone when you make changes?  What mechanism are you using to ensure that the name servers are returning the same results?

Answer (score 0):

I notice that NS.KIMSUFI.COM does not return the answer that KS3309528.KIMSUFI.COM does, perhaps this is the problem?  For our domains the secondary returns the same answer as primary, and yours has a response including this invalid hostname: "root.yt-stats.com." (see below)

Name Server: KS3309528.KIMSUFI.COM
   Name Server: NS.KIMSUFI.COM

## dig @ns.kimsufi.com beta.yt-stats.com

; <<>> DiG 9.7.0-P1 <<>> @ns.kimsufi.com beta.yt-stats.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 31253
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;beta.yt-stats.com.             IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
yt-stats.com.           300     IN      SOA     ks3309528.kimsufi.com. root.yt-stats.com. 2013030310 86400 3600 3600000 300

## dig @ks3309528.kimsufi.com beta.yt-stats.com

; <<>> DiG 9.7.0-P1 <<>> @ks3309528.kimsufi.com beta.yt-stats.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 11290
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;beta.yt-stats.com.             IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
beta.yt-stats.com.      86400   IN      CNAME   yt-stats.com.
yt-stats.com.           86400   IN      A       5.135.160.63

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
yt-stats.com.           86400   IN      NS      ks3309528.kimsufi.com.
yt-stats.com.           86400   IN      NS      ns.kimsufi.com.

Comment: Thx for helping me :) If i add 5.135.160.63 ns.kimsufi.com in /etc/host , this will be ok ?

Comment: no, it won't solve the problem, if that's what you mean